# Auto login to grafana from Web application using credentials or token

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, grafana

I have web application and from that web application I want to open grafana dashboard into an iframe. But I want to auto login to **grafana** and show the dashboard. So i will achieve it using credentials or authorization header if possible. Is there any other way to do this.

Comment: Hi did you find a solution to this?

Comment: [Automatic Authentication using Grafana API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57389522/automatic-authentication-using-grafana-api)

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on something similar at the moment.

Implementing a clean solution is being discussed in the following Github issue: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/3752, which does suggest some workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do the autologin using nginx and grafana `auth.proxy`.

I'd generate a link in this format: `http://grafana/?user=nayar&md5=2tutcea9nfdsfdsfdsw&expires=1505386800`

I've given full detail on this link: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/3752#issuecomment-329395036

Comment: Hi Nayar, I read your post in github issue, but I didn't understand how you generate `md5=2tutcea9nfdsfdsfdsw&expires=1505386800` for your username. Could you please explain more?